# How to run `conda` command when anaconda spyder is running?

Tags: terminal, anaconda, conda, spyder

My system is centos7, I installed `spyder` through `conda install spyder`.

I always `conda activate myenv`, then `spyder` to run spyder.Attached pls find screenshot:
[image]

If,now, I want to check packages list, I cannot input `conda myenv list` in terminal, because occpied by spyder.

How to run `conda` command when anaconda spyder is running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that you need to start Spyder as a background process in the console. In other words, you need to start Spyder like this

```
spyder&
```

The ampersand at the end is what frees the console for new commands to be entered on it. And it not only works for Spyder, but for any other Linux command.

Comment: I have a similar problem with some of my envs. For some reasons (group policy), I cannot use the ampersand character. For some of my envs, spyder (without &) works well (launching spyder and getting back to command line), but for some envs the spyder is launched without getting back to command line. The different behavior may have to do with the versions of packages.